# PLC not connecting to KEP Server (OPC)

Tags: plc, opc, kepserverex

We can't get our PLC to reliably connect with KEPServerEX (OPC).

I was wondering if anyone else here at SOF has experience working with PLC and OPC. If so do they have any tips on making a reliable connection with our OPC Server. We currently use KEPServerEX  for our OPC, but **if** anyone knows a better program to use we are open to suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Kepware OPC server for MODBUS TCP, Simatic S7 and Yokogawa for more then 5 years on 4 servers in industrial environment without any problems. It was easy to set up and showed no problems during exploatation. Actually, it was so nice that we decided to not use it only when it doesn't support the device we have (which is rare, and mostly happens when I have to develop custom OPC server). Kepware OPC server is even able to use reserved PG connection for connection to Siemens PLCs (unlike Simatic OPC Server, this is good if you have limited number of connections like in CP343 LEAN version communication module). It will also save you $$$$$ if you use data from it in some historian like OsiSoft PI which charges per OPC server connections, since all Kepware OPC servers will show as single OPC server to Osisoft PI. The only thing that made me angry was that after some trial time it stopped without warning all servers (including licenced ones) when I was evaluating one new OPC server I was supposed to try out. Have you tried Kepware technical support? Have you checked your cabling? Are you aware that trial version will stop after some time?
As an alternative you can try Matrikon OPC servers. They are also very good and run without problems.

Comment: We did come to the conclusion that it was because we were using the trial version. But its good to hear that someone else has had good results with Kepware OPC servers.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Could you please up vote accepted answer? It is strange to see it accepted but with zero votes.